# How do I restrict the terminal window to the working region of a broken monitor?

Tags: command-line, server, display-resolution, monitor

I am currently running Ubuntu Server 24.04.02 LTS on my old laptop to run some side projects. Unfortunately the left portion of the laptop monitor has been damaged, so it has been quite difficult to do troubleshooting locally on the device.  I was wondering if there was any way to restrict the terminal/bash to a specific region of the monitor? I do not have a clickable interface on this installation, it's just the terminal when I log in. The only other solutions for this problem I have seen have been for installs with a window manager.

Thank you so much for the help!